# Finite Double integration in R- Studio Error

Tags: r, double, integration

I want to integrate a two variable function in R studio using "cubature" package in R but when submitting code getting the error.
I don't know whether the problem is in writing function or using function.
I have given the two codes that I am using followed by the error in italic font;

1. Code:

> f10 <- function(x, y) {1/(sqrt(1- x^2) * sqrt(1 - y^2))}

> (a10 <- adaptIntegrate(f10, lower = c(0, 0), upper = c(1, 1))$integral)

Error :
*Error in f(x, ...) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
Called from: f(x, ...)*

2. Code:

> f10 <- function(x) {1/(sqrt(1- x^2) * sqrt(1 - y^2))}

> (a10 <- adaptIntegrate(f10, lower = c(0, 0), upper = c(1, 1))$integral)

Error:
*Error in f(x, ...) : object 'y' not found
Called from: f(x, ...)*

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `f10` needs to be a single vector, not two scalars.  For example,

```r
library(cubature)
f10 <- function(x) {
  1/(sqrt(1- x[1]^2) * sqrt(1 - x[2]^2))
}
adaptIntegrate(f10, 
               lower = c(0, 0), 
               upper = c(1, 1))$integral
#> [1] 2.467393
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>